# How to know if a database has been updated from C# web application

Tags: c#

I have a web page build using c#

in my web user send his/her info

the server should process these info. which may take a minute or 2

I want to show the user a waiting message and then redirect them to another page once process finishes

my question is how I can let my web application know that a record has been updated in the database

I was thinking of a timer to check the DB every 15 seconds and once get the updates to redirect to another page

I wonder if this is the best way to handle such issue or there is a better way?

Comment: There are other ways, yes. Better is subjective. They take some setting up though. Having your client maintain a connection to the server (SignalR) so the server can push updates to the client is the usual way. For what it's worth, if you're happy with the simple polling route I'd go with it - it's cheap, easy, not horrific on resources, resilient to failure and can be done with your existing tech. If the user interaction is such that they don't need to jump on the response quickly or it'll take hours, perhaps a "thanks, we'll send you an email when it's done" might be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `threads` and show the user a message or redirect them to a new page when the database thread operation is complete.

I enter it under my solution.

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(operationDatatoDB));
thread.Start();
```

operationDatatoDB Method

```
void operationDatatoDB()
{
    //db operation
    //...........
    //...........
    //end operation


    //show message or redirect new page
}
```